# Invalid Date in Angular 2

Tags: c#, json, angular, date

I am trying to convert Microsoft JSON Date into a readable format in angular 2 but it says "Invalid Date" as result in my console.log. What I am trying to do is:

```
formatJsonDate(jsonDate) {
    return (new Date(parseInt(jsonDate)));
};

testDate() {
    var testJsonDate = this.formatJsonDate('/Date(1224043200000)/');
    console.log(testJsonDate);
}
```

I actually want to show date in the format "dd-MM-yyyy".
Any help regarding this?

Comment: Attempting to use parseInt on `/Date(1224043200000)/` results in `NaN` because it's trying to parse a non-integer value.

Comment: Why not just `formatJsonDate('1224043200000') `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Microsoft JSON Date you refer to is `'/Date(1224043200000)/'` and this will be always the format, then you can extract the numeric value with a RegExp and get the date.

```
formatJsonDate(jsonDate) {
  return new Date(+(jsonDate.match(/\d+/)[0])); 
}
```